# Does HP TouchPad supports HTML5's offline application (Manifest)

Tags: html, offlineapps, offline-browsing, touchpad, manifest.cache

I have a webapp using offline support (a manifest file). It works correctly on Androids, iOS, RIM, and then some.

It doesn't work on TouchPad though. If I refresh the app without connectivity, I get a "No Internet Connection" error. Did anybody got a manifest file to work on TouchPads?

Here's part of my code:

My main HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline/newspro.manifest">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        .
        .
        .
```

And the manifest file (sent as text/cache-manifest mime type):
    CACHE MANIFEST

```
CACHE:
../index.html
../css/stylesheet.css
../images/logo.png
../images/progress.gif
../images/warning.png
../js/global.js

NETWORK:
*
# revision 351234
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/shichuan/mobile-html5-boilerplate/wiki/HTML5-Mobile-Support, webOS supports appcache, so I imagine it *should* work on TouchPads, at least relatively recent ones.  Have you tested on other webOS devices?

Comment: no. I don't have any other WebOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title post is "Yes" based on https://github.com/shichuan/mobile-html5-boilerplate/wiki/HTML5-Mobile-Support.  TouchPad's are WebOS and WebOS supports appcache.

As for the answer to the question in the body of your post--has anyone gotten it to work?--I don't know about that, unfortunately.